# how to achieve audio preloading in qt

Tags: qt, audio, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to use QMediaPlayer and QMediaList to play streaming audio. I want to add an audio preloading feature to my application, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have several questions here.

- When does the audio loading happended? Does it happened when calling `QMediaPlayer.play` or `QMediaList.addMedia`?
- Do QMediaPlayer or QMediaList do preloading in their implementations?
- If QMeidaPlayer and QMediaList haven't implemented preloading, what can I do to add this feature? Does Qt support any methods to do audio loading outside qt but do audio playing in it?

Comment: You can read the media file and store in a `QByteArray`, since `QByteArray` derives from `QIODevice`.

Comment: Since you do not want to preload all streams (e.g. >100 entries) you will have to preload on pressing play. Since streams are default realtime based you will have to "pause" playing and filling your buffer. If you are not only using live-streams you could buffer full speed and play from local cache (e.g. ``QByteArray``)

Comment: @zen so do you mean that QMediaPlayer and QMediaList doesn't support preloading and I have to do it myself?

Comment: I don't know whether `QMediaPlayer` support it but I think you can do it if necessary. And it is not difficult.@sandnon